# Multiple window plots from a single .txt file with data seperated by blank lines, #GNUPLOT

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I am running a Genetic Algorithm and the data of all the generations are stored in a single file as shown below. I want to plot each generation data on seperate windows with the title, which is to be taken from the line after the blank line starting with #.  There is a "#" before every generation title.

Note:There is no blank line after the title of each generation, and there is one blank line after the data of each generation and before the title of the next.

## +1,0

0    +0.00000    +0.00000    +0.00000    +0.748570    +1.00000    +0.748566    +0.998268
1    +0.100000    +6.93889e-18    +0.0588764    +0.716775    +1.00000    +0.760250    +0.994118

## +1,1

0    +0.00000    +0.00000    +0.785398    +0.748570    +1.00000    +0.748566    +0.998268
1    +0.0707107    +0.0707107    +0.685398    +0.764702    +1.00000    +0.668186    +0.992386
2    +0.148127    +0.134009    +0.585398    +0.786377    +1.00000    +0.609907    +0.986533

## +1,2

0    +0.00000    +0.00000    +0.785398    +0.747954    +1.00000    +0.747951    +0.998268
1    -0.0707107    -0.0707107    +0.685398    +0.750520    +1.00000    +0.619691    +1.00415
2    -0.148127    -0.134009    +0.585398    +0.753922    +1.00000    +0.538897    +1.01000

I have tried the basic plot command:

```
          plot "r.txt" using (-7+$2):(-7+$3) with lines
```

But this command plots all the generations in a single window, I want it to show each generation on a separate window.
Example:

Window1:- +1,0 generation plot

Window2:- +1,1 generation plot ....................so on

PS: Sorry if my question is vague and generalized poorly, I am new here and have to understand the proper way to generalize my question before posting

Comment: Would be nice if you could add some commands you tried.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is badly framed or if the question has already been discussed. Please let me know regarding my mistakes so that I can avoid them next time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with seperate window but to select only one of the blocks write something as:

```
plot '...' every :::1::1 u ...
```

this would plot only the first block...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Multiple window in the sense I wanted to open different image windows, one window for each generation plot. The code you mentioned plots one block in a window, I want an output where second block would be plotted in a different window.....and so on.

Comment: Use e.g. `set terminal wxt 1; plot ...; set terminal wxt 2; plot...` to get more windows.